# unable to extract value from struct using swift JSON Decoder

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decoder

[Click Here for JSON image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTmwW.png)

Please tell me the way to extract the value of "ranking". Check the image first.

My struct :

```
struct Result2 : Codable{
    let rankings : [Myrankings3]

    struct Myrankings3 : Codable{
        let ranking : String
    }
}
```

JSON code

```
do {
    let finalResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result2.self, from: data!)
    print(finalResult)        
    // I want to get the value of ranking which is of type string 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images. Post the JSON as text.

Comment: I'm new here. Thanks for th advice .But tell me how to get the value of "ranking" in the given struct

Comment: JSON URL : https://stark-spire-93433.herokuapp.com/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root object (`finalResult`) iterate the array `rankings`

```
let finalResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result2.self, from: data!)
for myRanking in finalResult.rankings {
      print(myRanking.ranking)
}
```

Comment: Please ask a new question and add more information for example the actual error you get.